# Start solr cloud and attach to existing collection

Tags: windows, solr9

I'm trying to run solr 9 on windows. I've created a collection and indexed some files but cannot figure out how to start solr in cloud mode and connect to my existing collection. The docs don't show any argument for something like this:
`solr start -cloud  -<arg> myCollection -m 2g`

I'm hoping to start solr with some script on restart of its host box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

`solr start -cloud -s example/cloud/node1/solr -p 8983`

You can select the node in the cloud using the -s flag.

References Page:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/getting-started/tutorial-solrcloud.html